# Defining an attribute to has_and_belongs_to_many relationship in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Lets say I want to create a database of finished coding projects, developers, and their roles.

The models look like this:

```
project has_and_belongs_to_many developers
developers has_and_belongs_to_many projects
```

The developers_projects table look like this:

```
int: developer_id, project_id
string: role
```

Lets day I have 3 Developers and 2 projects with their respective id and names as

```
1, Ashley
2, Bob
3, Charles

1, Tic Tac Toe
2, Snake
```

And their actual roles being

```
Project 1:
- Manager: Ashley
- Coder: Bob, Charles

Project 2:
- Manager: Charles
- Coder: Ashley
```

Is it possible to define a managers and coders object under projects?

like:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :developers
    has_and_belongs_to_many :managers, :class_name => "developers", :condition => "role = 'manager'"
    has_and_belongs_to_many :coders, :class_name => "developers", :condition => "role = 'coder'"
end
```

(this does not work)

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`has_and_belongs_to_many` allows to create join tables without declaring model. As far as you want to have attribute in this table you should create separate model, for example, ProjectRoles in your case:

```
class ProjectRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :developer
  belongs_to :project

  attr_accessible :role
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :manager_roles, :class_name => "ProjectRole", 
                           :conditions => { :role => 'manager' }
  has_many :managers, :through => manager_roles
end

class Developer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_roles
  has_many :projects, :through => project_roles
end
```

Comment: I tried Developer.find(1).projects and it gives me uninitialized constant Developer::Projects. Developer.find(1).project_roles would return correctly though

Comment: actually I realized the belongs_to in Project Role should be defined without 's's. editing and accepting. Thank you!